# Need help with creating a form with KBasic

Tags: application-development, ide

I have installed KBasic on my Ubuntu to create a simple form(as of now) which will have a database backend.

The problem is ,as per the KBasic help,i have to click on any component i want for eg button n then click on the form where i want to add it...fairly simple...like VB...But,its not happening! I click on it and then on the form,but i do not get anything on the form!

Can anyone help me with how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that there haven't been any answers here, you might want to ask at http://www.kbasic.com/forum/